# oracle Update with join syntax

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

I'm new to oracle 8i PL/SQL, please help me with PL/SQL simple update, I'm familiar with T-SQL, but confuse in PL/SQL.

```
Update a
SET a.column = null
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.fields1=b.fields1
WHERE a.fields3=[criteria]
```

Any help would be appreciate,

Rgds
Affan

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't support update with join syntax. 
But you can do it as follows :

```
update table1 a set field1 = null 
where field3 = [criteria] and 
    exists (select 1 from table2 where field1 = a.field1)
```

Comment: @affan25, if this answer has solved your issue you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (if you want to) by clicking the green tick. This indicates to the wider community that your problem has been solved and grants the answerer and you some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but this might work:

```
merge into table1 t
enter code hereusing (select a.IdColumnt from table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.fields1=b.fields1 WHERE a.fields3=[criteria]) u
on t.IdColumnt = u.IdColumnt
when matched then update set t.column = null;

commit;
```